# Is it possible to nest wordpress shortcodes that are the same shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I know it is possible to nest shortcodes if they use the do_shortcode wrapper, however, the codex states:

"However the parser will fail if a shortcode macro is used to enclose another macro of the same name:"

Is there a way around this?

for example if I have the a shortcode to make a div such as:

```
[div]some content in a div[/div]
```

I want to be able to use:

```
[div]
    [div]a nested div[/div]
[/div]
```

but this will fail with the standard do_shortcode wrapper.

My temporary workaround is the duplicate the shortcode with _parent appended to the name but than I can only nest 1 level deep unless I created div_parent1, div_parent2 etc...

Comment: What you look for is documented in the wordpress documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes

Comment: @hakre can you point me to which line in there shows it - from what I can see it only says what I quoted in the question that it is not possible to nest shortcodes of the same name due to a limitation in the context-free regexp parser.

Comment: Well, read: *"The shortcode parser correctly deals with nested shortcode macros, provided their handler functions support it by recursively calling `do_shortcode()`"* - just do that. call `do_shortcode()` in your own shortcode hook. That's how it is done in Wordpress. -- That is the first line of the section "Nested Shortcodes" by the way.

Comment: Hmm, right, misread you. The issue is known however, it has been reported about two years ago: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14481

Comment: @hakre thanks for the input - for this particular shortcode 1 level of nesting should be enough so I'm just going to stick with a duplicated shortcode with _parent appended. That should save me some processing resources and dev time.

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing the shortcode there is a simple solution.  You can write several shortcodes that call the same function.  I have shortcodes for creating html blocks such as divs, and have several with names like div, block1, block2  eg.

```
add_shortcode('div', 'devondev_block');
add_shortcode('block', 'devondev_block');
add_shortcode('block2', 'devondev_block');
```

They all call the same function.  They can be nested as long as you remember to use different short codes.

The WordPress short code support suffers from the attempt to do the parsing with regex only. It is possible to do this sort of parsing with a mixture of regex, a finite state machine, and a stack. That approach can handle nesting and can be very fast, especially when there are very few shortcodes.  Every time I encounter this I'm tempted to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks - as mentioned in the question this is what I ended up sticking with but with '_parent' appended to the shortcode for one of them as I only need to nest 1 deep.

Answer (score 1):

The API tells it like it is, thus this is not possible:

`This is a limitation of the context-free regexp parser used by do_shortcode() - it is very fast but does not count levels of nesting, so it can't match each opening tag with its correct closing tag in these cases.`

The functions in question in the latest version (3.4.2) are:

```
function do_shortcode($content) {
    global $shortcode_tags;

    if (empty($shortcode_tags) || !is_array($shortcode_tags))
        return $content;

    $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
    return preg_replace_callback( "/$pattern/s", 'do_shortcode_tag', $content );
}

function get_shortcode_regex() {
    global $shortcode_tags;
    $tagnames = array_keys($shortcode_tags);
    $tagregexp = join( '|', array_map('preg_quote', $tagnames) );

    // WARNING! Do not change this regex without changing do_shortcode_tag() and strip_shortcode_tag()
    return
          '\\['                              // Opening bracket
        . '(\\[?)'                           // 1: Optional second opening bracket for escaping shortcodes: [[tag]]
        . "($tagregexp)"                     // 2: Shortcode name
        . '\\b'                              // Word boundary
        . '('                                // 3: Unroll the loop: Inside the opening shortcode tag
        .     '[^\\]\\/]*'                   // Not a closing bracket or forward slash
        .     '(?:'
        .         '\\/(?!\\])'               // A forward slash not followed by a closing bracket
        .         '[^\\]\\/]*'               // Not a closing bracket or forward slash
        .     ')*?'
        . ')'
        . '(?:'
        .     '(\\/)'                        // 4: Self closing tag ...
        .     '\\]'                          // ... and closing bracket
        . '|'
        .     '\\]'                          // Closing bracket
        .     '(?:'
        .         '('                        // 5: Unroll the loop: Optionally, anything between the opening and closing shortcode tags
        .             '[^\\[]*+'             // Not an opening bracket
        .             '(?:'
        .                 '\\[(?!\\/\\2\\])' // An opening bracket not followed by the closing shortcode tag
        .                 '[^\\[]*+'         // Not an opening bracket
        .             ')*+'
        .         ')'
        .         '\\[\\/\\2\\]'             // Closing shortcode tag
        .     ')?'
        . ')'
        . '(\\]?)';                          // 6: Optional second closing brocket for escaping shortcodes: [[tag]]
}
```

Comment: Yes I see that. I'm asking if there is a way around it - ie not using the do_shortcode but maybe some similar function that doesn't use the context free regexp parser but rather a parser that does count levels of nesting

Comment: In theory you could do that, but you would have to not use the standard shortcode functionality and attach it to the `the_content` filter or something similar. Probably best to not use the `[shortcode]` syntax to avoid conflicts with Wordpress.

Comment: You would also be sacrificing performance, parsing the content for nested patterns would be expensive.

Comment: Look at `wp-incudes/shortcodes.php` - you will need to duplicate this functionality and write your own regex parser as there are no hooks for modifying this behavior.

Comment: thanks for the input - for this particular shortcode 1 level of nesting should be enough so I'm just going to stick with a duplicated shortcode with _parent appended. That should save me some processing resources and dev time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the shortcodes again for the content in your shortcode. Example:

```
add_shortcode('div', function($attributes, $content, $tag) {
    ...
    do_shortcode($content);
    ...
});
```

See as well: [What is the best way to enable nested shortcodes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/33186/178) (Wordpress SE)

Just seeing: This does not solve the problem in Wordpress so does not answer your question. I thought it would have been fixed that until now.

Comment: This doesn't work with the same nested shortcode, per the docs.

Comment: Oh they are not yet using recursion even PCRE supports that? Hmm, well, then this indeed needs a bug report with Wordpress and is a limitation of the software. Patching `get_shortcode_regex` should fix this. Let me take a look if a patch exists.

Comment: [However the parser will fail if a shortcode macro is used to enclose another macro of the same name](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes) - it's a performance thing supposedly.

Comment: @doublesharp: Maybe. The regex does not look that well in any case, so actually performance wise this could be improved anyway.

Comment: Agreed, but it is what it is for now, although the many will love you if you offered a better patch for this regex :)

Comment: I think the problem here is that they did not follow the route they are doing with balance tags for HTML. It would be equally easy to do it that way and would allow much more.

Comment: @doublesharp: There is a suggestion in trac, give it some traction if you like to see some changes with the current status quo.

Comment: @doublesharp: Please read this: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/parse_with_regexp.html , it's probably easy to change the regex in the function with what is outlined there.

Comment: The other problem with the shortcode syntax is that like html <p> a close isn't always required.  So it is very hard to support nesting using a regex even with recursion.